# Installation incomplete of AutoCAD 2020

Tags: autocad, cad

I am trying to install AutoCAD 2020 with educational license. Every time I get this error screen:
[image: y]
I tried to follow the [How  do I fix this?](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/downloads/content/autodesk-licensing-service-update-for-2020-product-versions.html) link, but it didn't help. Any one have any ideas about this problem?
My OS is Windows 10.
**Note:** I have installed many AutoCAD versions before, starting from AutoCAD 2000 to AutoCAD 2019.

Comment: Can you provide an English screenshot of the Properties of the installer.  Looking to make sure the file is blocked.  Perform a [clean install](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/customer-service/download-install/remove-products/clean-uninstall) to avoid conflicts with the other versions you have installed previously.  You should also download the installer again.

Comment: You mean like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/58hnu.png

Comment: Specifically the Security tab

Comment: Here it is. https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5FhI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [removed the old program](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/customer-service/download-install/remove-products/remove-windows-products) and did a [clean uninstall](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/customer-service/download-install/remove-products/clean-uninstall), then reinstalled it, and it worked.